# How to conditionally and efficiently mange graphic device using dev.off() in R

Tags: r, plot

**Background:**

I often call my plotting functions using `source`. However, because each plotting function has its own `par(...)` settings, after I run the first plotting function, for the next successive plotting functions to show correctly in my graphic device, I run `dev.off()`. ***Below, I'm showing what I exactly do when I have 3 plotting functions written in 3 different R files using pseudo-R-codes.***

**Question:**

I was wondering **how I can avoid running `dev.off()` multiple times** to run each plotting function after I run my first plotting function?

```
### source 3 R files each containing a plotting function that plots something:

#1 source("C:/file1.path/file1.name.R")  
#2 source("C:/file2.path/file2.name.R")
#3 source("C:/file3.path/file3.name.R")

#1 Function in file 1: Beta (Low = '5%', High = '90%', cover = '95%')

## dev.off() # Now run this to reset the par(...) to default

#2 Function in file 2: Normal (Low = -5, High = 5, cover = '95%')

## dev.off() # Now run this to reset the par(...) to default

#3 Function in file 3: Cauchy (Low = -5, High = 5, cover = '90%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to store original par settings, change it within the function as required, and restore it at the end of the function using function exit code (`on.exit()`)

```
#FUNCTIONS
myf1 = function(x = rnorm(20)){
    original_par = par(no.readonly = TRUE) #store original par in original_par
    on.exit(par(original_par)) #reset on exiting function
    par(bg = "red") #Change par inside function as needed
    plot(x)
}

myf2 = function(x = rnorm(20)){
    original_par = par(no.readonly = TRUE)
    on.exit(par(original_par))
    plot(x, type = "l")
}

#USAGE
par(bg = "green") #Let's start by setting green background
myf1() #this has red background
myf2() #But this has green like in the start
par(bg = "pink") #Let's repeat with pink
myf1() #Red
myf2() #Pink
dev.off() #Let's reset par
myf1() #Red
myf2() #White
```